# Reading data to python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling with reading data into python dataframe. Am R programmer trying to do stuff in Python. So how would I read the following data into pandas dataframe? The data is actually the result of calling API.

Thanks.

b'{"mk_id":"1200011617609","doc_type":"sales_order","opr_code":"0","count_code":"1051885/2022","doc_date":"2022-08-23+02:00","partner":{"mk_id":"400020633177","business_entity":"false","taxpayer":"false","foreign_county":"true","customer":"Emilia Chabadova","street":"Ga\xc5\xa1tanov\xc3\xa1 2915/13","street_number":"2915/13","post_number":"92101","place":"Pie\xc5\xa1\xc5\xa5any","country":"Slovakia","count_code":"5770789334526546744","partner_contact":{"gsm":"+421949340254","email":"emily.chabadova@gmail.com"},"mk_address_id":"400020530565","country_iso_2":"SK","buyer":"true","supplier":"false"},"receiver":{"mk_id":"400020633177","business_entity":"false","taxpayer":"false","foreign_county":"true","customer":"Emilia Chabadova","street":"Ga\xc5\xa1tanov\xc3\xa1 2915/13","street_number":"2915/13","post_number":"92101","place":"Pie\xc5\xa1\xc5\xa5any","country":"Slovakia","count_code":"5770789334526546744","partner_contact":{"gsm":"+421949340254","email":"emily.chabadova@gmail.com"},"mk_address_id":"400020530565","country_iso_2":"SK","buyer":"true","supplier":"false"},"currency_code":"EUR","status_code":"Zaklju\xc4\x8dena","doc_created_email":"stifter.rok@gmail.com","buyer_order":"SK-956103","warehouse":"glavno","delivery_type":"Gls_sk","product_list":[{"count_code":"54","mk_id":"266405022384","code":"MSS","name":"Mousse","unit":"kos","amount":"1","price":"16.66","price_with_tax":"19.99","tax":"200"},{"count_code":"53","mk_id":"266405022383","code":"MIT","name":"Mitt","unit":"kos","amount":"1","price":"0","tax":"200"},{"count_code":"48","mk_id":"266404892511","code":"TM","name":"Tanning mist","name_desc":"TM","unit":"kos","amount":"1","price":"0","tax":"200"}],"extra_column":[{"name":"tracking_number","value":"91114278162"}],"sum_basic":"16.66","sum_tax_200":"3.33","sum_all":"19.99","sum_paid":"19.99","profit_center":"SHINE BROWN, PROIZVODNJA, TRGOVINA IN STORITVE, D.O.O.","bank_ref_number":"10518852022","method_of_payment":"Pla\xc4\x8dilo po povzetju","order_create_ts":"2022-08-23T09:43:00+02:00","created_ts":"2022-08-23T11:59:14+02:00","shipped_date":"2022-08-24+02:00","doc_link_list":[{"mk_id":"266412181173","count_code":"SK-MK-36044","doc_type":"sales_bill_foreign"},{"mk_id":"400015161112","count_code":"1043748/2022","doc_type":"warehouse_packing_list"},{"mk_id":"1200011617609","count_code":"1051885/2022","doc_type":"sales_order"}]}'

Answer (score 0):

you can start by doing something like this :

```
result = {"mk_id":"1200011617609","doc_type":"sales_order","opr_code":"0","count_code":"1051885/2022","doc_date":"2022-08-23+02:00","partner":{"mk_id":"400020633177","business_entity":"false","taxpayer":"false","foreign_county":"true","customer":"Emilia Chabadova","street":"Ga\xc5\xa1tanov\xc3\xa1 2915/13","street_number":"2915/13","post_number":"92101","place":"Pie\xc5\xa1\xc5\xa5any","country":"Slovakia","count_code":"5770789334526546744","partner_contact":{"gsm":"+421949340254","email":"emily.chabadova@gmail.com"},"mk_address_id":"400020530565","country_iso_2":"SK","buyer":"true","supplier":"false"},"receiver":{"mk_id":"400020633177","business_entity":"false","taxpayer":"false","foreign_county":"true","customer":"Emilia Chabadova","street":"Ga\xc5\xa1tanov\xc3\xa1 2915/13","street_number":"2915/13","post_number":"92101","place":"Pie\xc5\xa1\xc5\xa5any","country":"Slovakia","count_code":"5770789334526546744","partner_contact":{"gsm":"+421949340254","email":"emily.chabadova@gmail.com"},"mk_address_id":"400020530565","country_iso_2":"SK","buyer":"true","supplier":"false"},"currency_code":"EUR","status_code":"Zaklju\xc4\x8dena","doc_created_email":"stifter.rok@gmail.com","buyer_order":"SK-956103","warehouse":"glavno","delivery_type":"Gls_sk","product_list":[{"count_code":"54","mk_id":"266405022384","code":"MSS","name":"Mousse","unit":"kos","amount":"1","price":"16.66","price_with_tax":"19.99","tax":"200"},{"count_code":"53","mk_id":"266405022383","code":"MIT","name":"Mitt","unit":"kos","amount":"1","price":"0","tax":"200"},{"count_code":"48","mk_id":"266404892511","code":"TM","name":"Tanning mist","name_desc":"TM","unit":"kos","amount":"1","price":"0","tax":"200"}],"extra_column":[{"name":"tracking_number","value":"91114278162"}],"sum_basic":"16.66","sum_tax_200":"3.33","sum_all":"19.99","sum_paid":"19.99","profit_center":"SHINE BROWN, PROIZVODNJA, TRGOVINA IN STORITVE, D.O.O.","bank_ref_number":"10518852022","method_of_payment":"Pla\xc4\x8dilo po povzetju","order_create_ts":"2022-08-23T09:43:00+02:00","created_ts":"2022-08-23T11:59:14+02:00","shipped_date":"2022-08-24+02:00","doc_link_list":[{"mk_id":"266412181173","count_code":"SK-MK-36044","doc_type":"sales_bill_foreign"},{"mk_id":"400015161112","count_code":"1043748/2022","doc_type":"warehouse_packing_list"},{"mk_id":"1200011617609","count_code":"1051885/2022","doc_type":"sales_order"}]}
pd.DataFrame([result])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) and [json.normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
from ast import literal_eval
from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd


data = b'{"mk_id":"1200011617609","doc_type":"sales_order","opr_code":"0","count_code":"1051885/2022","doc_date":"2022-08-23+02:00","partner":{"mk_id":"400020633177","business_entity":"false","taxpayer":"false","foreign_county":"true","customer":"Emilia Chabadova","street":"Ga\xc5\xa1tanov\xc3\xa1 2915/13","street_number":"2915/13","post_number":"92101","place":"Pie\xc5\xa1\xc5\xa5any","country":"Slovakia","count_code":"5770789334526546744","partner_contact":{"gsm":"+421949340254","email":"emily.chabadova@gmail.com"},"mk_address_id":"400020530565","country_iso_2":"SK","buyer":"true","supplier":"false"},"receiver":{"mk_id":"400020633177","business_entity":"false","taxpayer":"false","foreign_county":"true","customer":"Emilia Chabadova","street":"Ga\xc5\xa1tanov\xc3\xa1 2915/13","street_number":"2915/13","post_number":"92101","place":"Pie\xc5\xa1\xc5\xa5any","country":"Slovakia","count_code":"5770789334526546744","partner_contact":{"gsm":"+421949340254","email":"emily.chabadova@gmail.com"},"mk_address_id":"400020530565","country_iso_2":"SK","buyer":"true","supplier":"false"},"currency_code":"EUR","status_code":"Zaklju\xc4\x8dena","doc_created_email":"stifter.rok@gmail.com","buyer_order":"SK-956103","warehouse":"glavno","delivery_type":"Gls_sk","product_list":[{"count_code":"54","mk_id":"266405022384","code":"MSS","name":"Mousse","unit":"kos","amount":"1","price":"16.66","price_with_tax":"19.99","tax":"200"},{"count_code":"53","mk_id":"266405022383","code":"MIT","name":"Mitt","unit":"kos","amount":"1","price":"0","tax":"200"},{"count_code":"48","mk_id":"266404892511","code":"TM","name":"Tanning mist","name_desc":"TM","unit":"kos","amount":"1","price":"0","tax":"200"}],"extra_column":[{"name":"tracking_number","value":"91114278162"}],"sum_basic":"16.66","sum_tax_200":"3.33","sum_all":"19.99","sum_paid":"19.99","profit_center":"SHINE BROWN, PROIZVODNJA, TRGOVINA IN STORITVE, D.O.O.","bank_ref_number":"10518852022","method_of_payment":"Pla\xc4\x8dilo po povzetju","order_create_ts":"2022-08-23T09:43:00+02:00","created_ts":"2022-08-23T11:59:14+02:00","shipped_date":"2022-08-24+02:00","doc_link_list":[{"mk_id":"266412181173","count_code":"SK-MK-36044","doc_type":"sales_bill_foreign"},{"mk_id":"400015161112","count_code":"1043748/2022","doc_type":"warehouse_packing_list"},{"mk_id":"1200011617609","count_code":"1051885/2022","doc_type":"sales_order"}]}'

df = pd.DataFrame(BytesIO(data))
df[0] = df[0].str.decode("utf-8").apply(literal_eval)
df = pd.json_normalize(
        data=df.pop(0),
        record_path="product_list",
        meta=["mk_id", "doc_type", "opr_code", "count_code", "doc_date", "currency_code",
              "status_code", "doc_created_email", "buyer_order", "warehouse", "delivery_type"],
        meta_prefix="meta."
    )

print(df.to_markdown())

|    |   count_code |        mk_id | code   | name         | unit   |   amount |   price |   price_with_tax |   tax | name_desc   |    meta.mk_id | meta.doc_type   |   meta.opr_code | meta.count_code   | meta.doc_date    | meta.currency_code   | meta.status_code   | meta.doc_created_email   | meta.buyer_order   | meta.warehouse   | meta.delivery_type   |
|---:|-------------:|-------------:|:-------|:-------------|:-------|---------:|--------:|-----------------:|------:|:------------|--------------:|:----------------|----------------:|:------------------|:-----------------|:---------------------|:-------------------|:-------------------------|:-------------------|:-----------------|:---------------------|
|  0 |           54 | 266405022384 | MSS    | Mousse       | kos    |        1 |   16.66 |            19.99 |   200 | nan         | 1200011617609 | sales_order     |               0 | 1051885/2022      | 2022-08-23+02:00 | EUR                  | Zaključena         | stifter.rok@gmail.com    | SK-956103          | glavno           | Gls_sk               |
|  1 |           53 | 266405022383 | MIT    | Mitt         | kos    |        1 |    0    |           nan    |   200 | nan         | 1200011617609 | sales_order     |               0 | 1051885/2022      | 2022-08-23+02:00 | EUR                  | Zaključena         | stifter.rok@gmail.com    | SK-956103          | glavno           | Gls_sk               |
|  2 |           48 | 266404892511 | TM     | Tanning mist | kos    |        1 |    0    |           nan    |   200 | TM          | 1200011617609 | sales_order     |               0 | 1051885/2022      | 2022-08-23+02:00 | EUR                  | Zaključena         | stifter.rok@gmail.com    | SK-956103          | glavno           | Gls_sk               |
```